# C++ Spaceship operator <=> and std::sort with user defined type

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I'm trying to use `std::sort()` on a `vector` of `shared_ptr<Card>`. I created a function that implements the spaceship operator. I couldn't simply overload it on `Card` because the container refers to `shared_ptr<Card>`, not the `Card` itself. The `std::sort()` works with a function that implements a `<` comparison, but not a `<=>` comparison.

```
std::strong_ordering compare(std::shared_ptr<Card> left, std::shared_ptr<Card> right)
{
    int leftManaCost = left->getManaCost();
    int rightManaCost = right->getManaCost();
    return std::tie(leftManaCost) <=> std::tie(rightManaCost);
}

bool compareJustMinor(std::shared_ptr<Card> left, std::shared_ptr<Card> right) 
{ 
    return (left->getManaCost() < right->getManaCost()); 
}

void Deck::Print()
{
    std::sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(), compare); //works with compareJustMinor
```

I´ll summarize the information that may be relevant

1. `Deck` is a class that has a member `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards;`
2. `Card` is a base class with a pure virtual function

I'm kind of rusty on C++ and new to the `<=>` operator, so I may be missing/misunderstanding something obvious.

Here is the error log:

```
>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7363,21): error C2678: binary '!': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::strong_ordering' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7355,1): message : could be 'built-in C++ operator!(bool)'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7355,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(std::strong_ordering)'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7425): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_RanIt,_RanIt> std::_Partition_by_median_guess_unchecked<_RanIt,std::strong_ordering(__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<Card>,std::shared_ptr<Card>)>(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _RanIt=std::shared_ptr<Card> *,
1>            _Pr=std::strong_ordering (__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<Card>,std::shared_ptr<Card>)
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7455): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Sort_unchecked<std::shared_ptr<Card>*,std::strong_ordering(__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<Card>,std::shared_ptr<Card>)>(_RanIt,_RanIt,__int64,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _RanIt=std::shared_ptr<Card> *,
1>            _Pr=std::strong_ordering (__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<Card>,std::shared_ptr<Card>)
1>        ]
1>D:\C++ Projects\MTG\Deck.cpp(99): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::sort<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<_Ty>>>,std::strong_ordering(__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<Card>,std::shared_ptr<Card>)>(const _RanIt,const _RanIt,_Pr)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::shared_ptr<Card>,
1>            _RanIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::shared_ptr<Card>>>>,
1>            _Pr=std::strong_ordering (__cdecl *)(std::shared_ptr<Card>,std::shared_ptr<Card>)
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7363,15): error C2088: '!': illegal for struct
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7367,81): error C2678: binary '!': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::strong_ordering' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7355,1): message : could be 'built-in C++ operator!(bool)'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7355,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(std::strong_ordering)'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7367,75): error C2088: '!': illegal for struct
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7378,29): error C2451: a conditional expression of type 'std::strong_ordering' is not valid
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7378,29): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7391,29): error C2451: a conditional expression of type 'std::strong_ordering' is not valid
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include\algorithm(7391,29): message : No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words what you believe `std::tie(leftManaCost) <=> std::tie(rightManaCost)` does that `leftManaCost <=> rightManaCost` doesn't, or vice versa?

Comment: I found it to be the most common implementation of <=>, without much thought. I see now that it works as a tiebreaker and is useless here. Still, removing std::tie doesn't appear to fix or change anything

Comment: Does this `compare` fulfill the requirements of the [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) comparison predicate, since it does **not** look like `bool cmp(const Type1& a, const Type2& b);`?  (Assuming you can get the `std::strong_ordering` to work correctly.)

Comment: If you want to implement the `<=>` operator on `Card` itself, you can. Simply dereference the `shared_ptr`s in `compare()` to access the `Card` objects, eg: `auto compare(std::shared_ptr<Card> left, std::shared_ptr<Card> right) { return *left <=> *right; }`

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `<=>` is not removed from `std::tuple`. Using `std::tie(...) <=> std::tie(...)` is a common idiom.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator which `std::sort` expects should satisfy the requirement of a *Compare*, i.e. it should behave like a `<` operator.

Your code should work if you pass `compare_just_minor` to `std::sort` instead of `compare`.
Here is a working example:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Card {
    int mana_cost;
};

std::strong_ordering compare(std::shared_ptr<Card> a, std::shared_ptr<Card> b) {
    return a->mana_cost <=> b->mana_cost;
}

bool compare_just_minor(std::shared_ptr<Card> a, std::shared_ptr<Card> b) {
    return std::is_lt(compare(a, b));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Card>> cards;
    std::sort(cards.begin(), cards.end(), compare_just_minor);
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vKsK763e6).*

That being said, the `<=>` operator is normally defined directly for a class, not for a smart pointer of that class:

```cpp
struct Card {
    int mana_cost;
    // return std::strong_ordering, but we can let the compiler
    // figure out all the details
    friend auto operator<=>(const Card&, const Card&) = default;
};

// ...

// note: std::ranges::sort is more concise
std::ranges::sort(cards, [](const auto& p0, const auto& p1) {
    // < is automatically delegated to <=> for Card
    return *p0 < *p1;
});
```

The use of `std::shared_ptr` is also questionable. Chances are you could just use `std::vector<Card>` directly.

---

*See also: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/5740428)*